# Concatenation of two strings into one in C

Tags: c

From The C Programming Language, by KRC

> Given the definition
>
> ```
> #define tempfile(dir)    #dir "%s"
> ```
>
> the macro call tempfile(/usr/tmp) yields
>
> ```
> "/usr/tmp" "%s"
> ```
>
> which will subsequently be catenated into a single string.

Which rule does the concatenation of the two strings at the end follow?

Is the rule for macros in preprocessing, or for strings in C in compilation ?

Answer (score 3):

This happens according to one of the phases of the translation.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §5.1.1.2/p1.4 and p1.6, (*according to the order*)

> Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, and
>   _Pragma unary operator expressions are executed. [...]

and

> Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

Comment: I would add that preprocessing is over at the end of phase 4 and concatenation happens in phase 6. Also it's list item 6 on paragraph 1, not paragraph 6.